# Issue in accessing and converting Blob image in android from MySql database.- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: android, mysql, database, bitmap, blob

I am using RDS MySql to store blob image and created web call in netbeans to store and access the data from the database. Android studio is getting data from the netbeans webcall. 
My Issue is - i am getting bytes array of blob image from netbeans but is unable to convert that into imageview.

```
    //Bytes Array from database
str1="-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,24,8,6,0,0,0,-32,119,61,-8,0,0,0,6,98,75,71,68,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,-96,-67,-89,-109,0,0,0,123,73,68,65,84,72,-119,99,96,24,-50,-32,63,20,83,-92,-114,-119,106,-50,33,-46,2,15,6,6,-122,-57,12,-88,46,-6,79,0,35,-85,123,4,53,3,39,120,68,-124,-127,-124,-16,35,100,3,25,-47,44,32,38,-52,-119,1,112,115,-23,30,7,84,7,44,56,-60,-47,-125,-114,88,-128,17,-60,67,63,-120,6,44,14,-16,1,108,73,25,103,-100,13,-3,32,26,-6,22,-112,19,-55,36,101,66,-70,7,-47,99,40,77,110,81,-115,108,6,86,-32,-63,64,89,-99,64,-80,-62,25,122,0,0,35,-14,69,34,31,-57,22,-56,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,-82,66,96,-126".



 byte[] outImage=(str1.getBytes());
  ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
  Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);           
  itemImage.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

ERROR : [image]Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'